# One to many relationship table update laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following models:

**Page.php** and **Content.php** in one to many relationship.

Their table structure are as follows:

**pages**

**id | title | slug**

**contents**

**id | page_id | section_title | section_content**

In my edit view the `section_title` and `section_content` fields can be generated dynamically.

**i.e: User can add more sections for content if they want to.**

Below is the snippet from edit page:

```html
@foreach ($page->content as $content)

<div class="row fieldGroup" id="dataRow{{$content->id}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="contentID[]" value="{{$content->id}}">
  <div class="col-sm-10  ">
    <div class="form-group floating-label {{$errors->has('sectionTitle') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
      <input type="text" name="sectionTitle[]" id="sectionTitle" class="form-control" value="{{$content->sectionTitle}}"> @if($errors->has('sectionTitle'))
      <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('sectionTitle') }}</span> @endif
      <label for="sectionTitle">Section Title</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2  ">
    @if($loop->first)
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success addMore">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Section
    </a>
    @else
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger removeData" id="id-delete" data-id="{{$content->id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a> @endif
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12  ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4>Section Content</h4>
      <textarea name="sectionContent[]" class="editor">{{$content->sectionContent}}</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

And below is the snippet from update method from the controller:

```js
$page - > title = $request - > title;
$page - > slug = Str::slug($request - > title, '-');
$page - > save();

$contents = Content::where('page_id', $page - > id) - > get();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request - > sectionTitle); $i++) {
  foreach($contents as $db) {
    if (isset($request - > contentID[$i]) && $db - > id == $request - > contentID[$i]) {
      $content = Content::find($request - > contentID[$i]);
      $content - > sectionTitle = $request - > sectionTitle[$i];
      $content - > sectionContent = $request - > sectionContent[$i];
      $content - > save();
    } else {
      $new = new Content;
      $new - > page_id = $page - > id;
      $new - > sectionTitle = $request - > sectionTitle[$i];
      $new - > sectionContent = $request - > sectionContent[$i];
      $new - > save();
    }
  }
}
```

The trouble I'm having is if user clicks the update button after editing the content. The each contents are saved more than once.

**i.e:If there are 3 contents then each content is saved 3 times**

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you have the loop twice, replace your code with below

```
$page-> title = $request->title;
$page-> slug = Str::slug($request->title, '-');
$page-> save();

$contents = Content::where('page_id', $page->id)->get();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($request-> sectionTitle); $i++) {

    if (isset($request->contentID[$i])) {
        Content::updateOrCreate([
            'id' => $request->contentID[$i];
            'page_id' => $page->id;
            'sectionTitle' => $request->sectionTitle[$i],
            'sectionTitle' => $request->sectionTitle[$i],
            'destination' => $request->sectionContent[$i]],
        );
    } else {
        $new = new Content;
        $new-> page_id = $page->id;
        $new-> sectionTitle = $request->sectionTitle[$i];
        $new-> sectionContent = $request->sectionContent[$i];
        $new-> save();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you